# how to upload users into lync using lync api

Tags: lync

I want to upload users into lync by an xml file. is there any lync api or c# code to do it??
I have xml file like below

```
                <ns1:LyncOnlineAcpUsers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/mco/2011/02/acp">-<ns1:ACPUser><ns1:Username>first.last@test.com</ns1:Username>-<ns1:UserAudioConferencingInfo>-<ns1:Provider><ns1:Identity>BT Conferencing</ns1:Identity></ns1:Provider><ns1:TollNumber>17209882090</ns1:TollNumber><ns1:TollFreeNumber>18666708282</ns1:TollFreeNumber><ns1:Passcode>99999999</ns1:Passcode></ns1:UserAudioConferencingInfo></ns1:ACPUser></ns1:LyncOnlineAcpUsers>
```

Comment: Do you mean creating actual Lync users or a contact list entries?

Comment: i want to create actual lync users with an xml file. in short I am having an xml file in which we are having some pass code and toll free no and want to update them through code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own script to do this, with (at least) the following steps:

- Load the XML and loop through all users, then for each user:
- Create the user in Active Directory.
- Enable the new AD user for Lync.
- Enable the Lync user for Enterprise voice (since you have a phone number I assume you want this).

These individual steps can be easily done with powershell, look for the following commands:

- `Get-Content` for reading an XML file.
- `New-ADUser` for creating an AD user.
- `Enable-CsUser` for creating a Lync user.
- `Set-CsUser` for enabling a Lync user for voice.

Comment: These users are already added in the active directory we just need to set the passcode and tollfree no.s for these users . The option is present in the Lync admin portal to import dialin users to Lync server. We are looking for an api that will do the same take the XMl file and upload the same into the Lync online server.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use PowerShell.
Google "LyncOnlineConnector", and once downloaded and installer use "load-module lynconlineconnector".
After that, you will have to create a session to your tennant.
In that session, you can use "set-csuseracp" and feed that your details, such as identifier (email) toll/tollfree numbers, passcode, provider etc.